# Can I use "on-send" in Outlook 2002 build with shared mailboxes?

Tags: office-js

I'm developing an on-send add-in. However, there are those in my organization that will need to be given permissions to another mailbox: case in point, a secretary who sends meetings or emails for his/her boss.

I'm reading that the on-send 2002 build won't work in this case. Is that true?

Thank you,
Donna

Comment: The On-send feature is available for clients with a min build of version 1910 (build 12130.20272) or later.

Comment: Also, sharedFolders is also supported in the same version of Outlook as above. Both these features will require a manifest change to support ItemSend and SharedFolders to work.